# Display a specific line from text file in a div tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a txt file in my site "sentences".
I want to display a specific line from the text file, say line 5, in a 
tag on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need a function to request the text file (code from [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript--net-4855)).

```
function load(url, callback) {
    var xhr;

    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else {
        var versions = ["MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0", 
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0", 
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",
                        "Microsoft.XmlHttp"]

         for(var i = 0, len = versions.length; i < len; i++) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
                break;
            }
            catch(e){}
         } // end for
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = ensureReadiness;

    function ensureReadiness() {
        if(xhr.readyState < 4) {
            return;
        }

        if(xhr.status !== 200) {
            return;
        }

        // all is well  
        if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
            callback(xhr);
        }           
    }

    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send('');
}
```

Then, request the file

```
load("somefile.txt", function(res){
    //do something here
});
```

Finally, set the `<div>` to the fifth line.

```
load("somefile.txt", function(res){
    document.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML = res.responseText.split("\n")[4];
});
```